# put elements into variable for naming (react)

Tags: reactjs

I tried to put elements into CustomModal variable:

```html
const CustomModal = (<div className="peoplelistpage-modal">
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content-empty" />
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content">
          <CustomForm
            krNameInput={this.state.krNameInput}
            handleKrNameInput={this.handleKrNameInput}
            enNameInput={this.state.enNameInput}
            handleEnNameInput={this.handleEnNameInput}
            positionInput={this.state.positionInput}
            handlePositionInput={this.handlePositionInput}
            departmentInput={this.state.departmentInput}
            handleDepartmentInput={this.handleDepartmentInput}
            doingInput={this.state.doingInput}
            handleDoingInput={this.handleDoingInput}
            btnValue="add"
            onBtnClick={this.handlePersonAddBtn}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content-empty" />
      </div>);
```

and used it in render() like this:

```js
render() {
//...
{ CustomModal }
//...
```

but, got an error:

react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {CustomModal}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Is there are any way to put elements into variable for naming?

Thanks.

----update-----
This is my full code of render :

```js
  render() {
    const CustomModal = (<div className="peoplelistpage-modal">
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content-empty" />
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content">
          <CustomForm
            krNameInput={this.state.krNameInput}
            handleKrNameInput={this.handleKrNameInput}
            enNameInput={this.state.enNameInput}
            handleEnNameInput={this.handleEnNameInput}
            positionInput={this.state.positionInput}
            handlePositionInput={this.handlePositionInput}
            departmentInput={this.state.departmentInput}
            handleDepartmentInput={this.handleDepartmentInput}
            doingInput={this.state.doingInput}
            handleDoingInput={this.handleDoingInput}
            btnValue="add"
            onBtnClick={this.handlePersonAddBtn}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content-empty" />
      </div>);
    const { people } = this.props.people.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* check login */}
        {this.props.auth.state.isLoggedIn ? (
          { CustomModal }
            ) : (
              <div />
            )}

            <div className="peoplelistpage-main">
              <h1 className="peoplelistpage-title">people list</h1>
              <div className="peoplelistpage-list-container">
                {people.map((person, index) => (
                  <ul className="peoplelistpage-list-ul" key={index}>
                    <li className="peoplelistpage-list-li">
                      {`${index + 1}.`}{" "}
                      <Link to={`${this.props.location.pathname}/${person.id}`}>
                        {person.kr_name}
                      </Link>{" "}
                      <button onClick={this.handlePersonDeleteBtn(person.id)}>
                        <DeleteUserIcon />
                      </button>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                ))}
              </div>
              <button onClick={this.openModal}>add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <CustomNotPermittedForm />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please post the full `render` code.

Comment: Where are you calling `CustomModal`?

Comment: @AdamGold That is what I want to do

Comment: Post the errored code - The one that you use and causes errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `div` or a `React.Fragment` to group elements together. `div`s are added to the DOM while Fragments are not. But in order for this work with state, you will have to use a function, as a static variable does not get updated with state values.

```
const CustomModal = () => (
      <React.Fragment>   // <-- or div
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal">
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content-empty" />
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content">
          <CustomForm
            krNameInput={this.state.krNameInput}
            handleKrNameInput={this.handleKrNameInput}
            enNameInput={this.state.enNameInput}
            handleEnNameInput={this.handleEnNameInput}
            positionInput={this.state.positionInput}
            handlePositionInput={this.handlePositionInput}
            departmentInput={this.state.departmentInput}
            handleDepartmentInput={this.handleDepartmentInput}
            doingInput={this.state.doingInput}
            handleDoingInput={this.handleDoingInput}
            btnValue="add"
            onBtnClick={this.handlePersonAddBtn}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="peoplelistpage-modal-content-empty" />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Usage

```
render() {
// ...
<CustomModal /> 
// ...
```